# Command `find` with single dash leading

Tags: find

In the manual page of command `find`,
I found options of `-depth`, `-delete`, `-exec` and etc
their leading symbol are single `-` instead of a double as `--`

Conversely, there's `git log --oneline` , `git log --graph`, and `--python`,
which are facile to distinguish the full names and abbreviated commands

Why does command `find` not follow such a practice.

Comment: Those are not options. Read the manual to learn the difference between options and expressions (predicates, primaries, whatever...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `find` is [a utility standardized by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/find.html) and `git` is not. The `git` developers are therefore free to implement its options/operands in whatever way they see fit.

POSIX utilities use `-` to introduce options, and implementations of these utilities (such as `ls` etc.) always implement them the way the POSIX standard prescribes. Then, for some utilities, there is an *additional* "long option" variant of some standard options along with extensions that are not even mentioned by POSIX.

In the case of `find`, these are not strictly "options" but "operands" (also referred to as "primaries" or "predicates" depending on what manual you're reading) that form "operand expressions" and act on the pathname that `find` is currently processing. The real options of standard `find` are just `-H` (dereference symbolic links) and `-L` (do not dereference symbolic links). You will notice the difference in the manual where options and operands are divided into separate sections.

Also for `git`, these are not "true option" when specified on the command line the way that it's done in the question, but operands. Options are always specified before non-options, and any command line arguments after the last option are just "operands".  They may well be translated to true options for the sub-command that `git` invokes later though.

Comment: I have learned about the topics multiple days, and prefer the clever name 'predicate' ^_^